# Hibernate HQL GroupBy in Oracle

Tags: oracle, hibernate, hql

I created this query using HQL with Hibernate and Oracle

```
select c from Cat c
 left join c.kittens k
 where (c.location= 1 OR c.location = 2)
 and (i.activo = 1)
 group 
 by c.id,
 c.name,
 c.fulldescription,
 c.kittens
 order by count(e) desc
```

The problem comes with the fact that in HQL you need to specify all fields in `Cat` in order to perform a Group By, but `fulldescription` is a CLOB, and you cannot group by by a CLOB (I get a "Not a Group By Expression" error. I've seen a few solutions around for a pure SQL sentence but none for HQL.

Comment: Im sorry I dont understand your question

Comment: In other words, do you _really_ want to group by `fulldescription` ? Or did you only add it in order to satisfy Oracle? Do you actually _need_ it in the output result?

Comment: In oracle you must include all common fields for a group by, otherwise you get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A serious issue `GROUP BY` of `HQL` because if you specify your object in `GROUP BY` and in your `SELECT` field list behaviours are differents. In `GROUP BY` has considered only id field but in SELECT field list all fields are considered.

So you can use a subquery with `GROUP BY` to return only id from your object, so that result becomes an input for the main query, like the follow I write for you.

Pay attention there are some alias table (i and e) not defined, so this query doesn't work, but you know as fixed.

Try this:

```
select c2 from Cat c2
where c2.id in (
  select c.id from Cat c
  left join c.kittens k
  where (c.location= 1 OR c.location = 2)
  and (i.activo = 1) <-- who is i alias??
  group by c.id)
order by count(e) desc <-- who is e alias???
```

Comment: That sounds like an elegant solution. Thanks.